# Запятая после деепричастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая, отделяющая деепричастный оборот от безличного (?) предложения?

Начиная разговор о значимости профессии (,) нелишне сказать и о материальном ее обеспечении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая в вашем предложении нужна. Запятая была бы не нужна, если "начиная" в примере было употреблено в качестве предлога "начиная с".

Ср.: **Начиная со** вторника погода резко изменилась (ср.: Со вторника погода резко изменилась).

В вашем предложении деепричастный оборот используется в безличном предложении с предикативным наречием "нелишне" и инфинитивом. Такие обороты обособляются.

Ср.: **Переходя дорогу,** следует смотреть по сторонам.
     **Слушая любимую музыку,** хорошо пить кофе.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое.